# How to search for a code pattern in a repository written by a given author?

Tags: git

How to search for a code pattern in a git repository written by a given author?

Eg: I want to find dynamic_cast lines introduced by author xx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git log --author=<author>` limits to commits written by an author. Combine that with `-S` or `-G` to search the patches. `-p` is probably useful to show the matched patches.

```
git log -p --author=pasanw -Sdynamic_cast
```

This will search from the current commit backwards. If you want to search all branches, add `--all`.

`-Gdynamic_cast` will find every commit whose patch contains `dynamic_cast`.

`-Sdynamic_cast` will only match commits which change the number of times `dynamic_cast` appears in the code.

For example...

```
-    dynamic_cast foo
+    dynamic_cast bar
```

`-Gdynamic_cast` will match the above change, `-Sdynamic_cast` will not.

See [the `git-log` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) for `-S` and `-G`'s idiosyncrasies.